# Как передать данные из python в js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, eel

Есть самый простой код, работающий на eel. В данном коде js получает данные из input и передаёт их в python, после чего python их выводит в cmd. Но мне надо передать эти данные в js и вывести во второй input. Как это сделать? Просто, если прописать в python `return self`, то js получает какую-то ерунду.

**Код**

```
import eel
eel.init('web')

@eel.expose
def plus(self):
    return self

eel.start('index.html', size=(700, 700), port=500)
```

**Страница**

```js
eel.expose(getItem);
function getItem(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    return input1;
}

function clicked(){
    let result = eel.plus(getItem());
    console.log(result);
}

var elem = document.getElementById("but");
elem.addEventListener("click", clicked);
```

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main *{
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Первая проба JS с Python</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Введите число" id="input1">
            <button id="but">Провести через Python</button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Получите, распишитесь" id="input2" disabled>
            <script src="js.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```